# TypeError: AWS.S3 is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, commonjs, aws-sdk-nodejs, npm-package

I am trying to create a NPM package but before I do that, I am testing it using the

`yarn link` command and then importing the node_module into another project.

This is what my package.json for the NPM package looks like

```
{
  "name": "qa-data-tool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "AWS uploads to S3 to support testing of invoicing PYCMA accounts",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index",
  "types": "dist/cjs/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/index.js"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "test typescript": "tsc ./src/testing.ts && node ./src/testing.js",
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ && prettier --write src/ && npm run build:esm && npm run build:cjs",
    "build:esm": "tsc",
    "build:cjs": "tsc --module CommonJS --outDir dist/cjs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.17.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.54",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.22.13",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/json2csv": "^5.0.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1200.0",
    "csv": "^6.2.0",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.7"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "js"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the folder sturcture of my project:

[image]

I am initializing the S3 bucket like so:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'; 
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as util from 'util';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve('.env') });
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile); 

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
});

/**
 * Uploads a file to the specified S3 bucket
 * @param filePath - relative path of the file you would like to upload e.g src/uploads/filename.txt
 * @param bucketName - the name of the bucket you would like to upload to e.g aspiration-galileo-staging-sftp-all/2023/09/
 */
export async function s3Upload(
  filePath: string,
  bucketName: string,
): Promise<void> {
  const fileData = await readFile(filePath);
  let extractFileName = filePath.split('/');
  const uploadFile = s3
    .putObject({
      Bucket: bucketName, //bucket name to upload your file too
      Key: extractFileName[extractFileName.length - 1], //name of the file will be the last element in the array
      Body: fileData,
    })
    .promise(); 
  uploadFile
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(`File uploaded to s3 bucket: ${bucketName} successfully`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Now when I try to use these modules in my simple node.js package I get the following error:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
           ^

TypeError: AWS.S3 is not a constructor
```

can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this error message?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Sorry. updated the post with actual code

Comment: Do some more debugging, if it's not a constructor, what is `AWS.S3`? What is `AWS`.  Package.json should also not be an image...

Comment: I have had a lot of trouble with "yarn link" and third party dependencies. I suggest you just use npm pack in your dist folder and then install the tar file that is generated to see if that's your problem. Another thing to try would be using `require` instead of import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

had to change my code to

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as util from 'util';
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3.js'; 

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve('.env') });
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

const s3 = new S3({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
});

/**
 * Uploads a file to the specified S3 bucket
 * @param filePath - relative path of the file you would like to upload e.g src/uploads/filename.txt
 * @param bucketName - the name of the bucket you would like to upload to e.g aspiration-galileo-staging-sftp-all/2023/09/
 */
export async function s3Upload(
  filePath: string,
  bucketName: string,
): Promise<void> {
  const fileData = await readFile(filePath);
  let extractFileName = filePath.split('/');

  s3.upload(
    {
      Bucket: bucketName, //bucket name to upload your file too
      Key: extractFileName[extractFileName.length - 1], //name of the file will be the last element in the array
      Body: fileData,
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
    },
  );
}
```